# cannot mount usb drive

Tags: mount, usb, kali-linux

This is my first day on linux and I can't figure out how to mount a usb drive.
I plugged it and used `fdisk -l` to locate it. 
However when I type `mount /dev/sda1` it says that sda1 does not exist.

```
root@kali:/media# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 62.9 GB, 62932647936 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7651 cylinders, total 122915328 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x73876c0c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   122914815    61456384    b  W95 FAT32
root@kali:/media# mount /dev/sda1
mount: can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
root@kali:/media#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: it worked :D chy did I have to use the -t parameter? how did you know that it was iso9660?

Comment: You should use `-t` if you don't want to rely on `mount` guessing. My first thought was `vfat`, but after closer look of `fdisk` output it prints `W95 FAT32` as a system and this corresponds to iso9660 - I've check on my usb with linux livecd image, it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke mount in multiple ways such as the SYNOPSIS section in `man mount` describes:

```
 mount [-lhV]

 mount -a [-fFnrsvw] [-t vfstype] [-O optlist]

 mount [-fnrsvw] [-o option[,option]...]  device|dir

 mount [-fnrsvw] [-t vfstype] [-o options] device dir
```

In the same `man` page in the DESCRIPTION section it states:

```
 If only directory or device is given, for example:

        mount /dir

 then mount looks for a mountpoint and if not found then for a device in
 the /etc/fstab file
```

Since you only provide one argument, `mount` searches for `/dev/sda1` in the `/etc/fstab` file, cannot find an entry there, and complains.

You either have to make an entry in the `/etc/fstab`, or use:

```
 mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

assuming `/media/sda1` is an existing directory and that your `mount` recognises the format of the USB drive (if not specify it by using `-t`).

I am a bit amazed thought that Kali Linux is so unfriendly that it doesn't automatically mount the drive for you once it is plugged in.